# OpenCV native library not loaded with Maven

Tags: java, maven, opencv

I am trying to run a basic program that uses OpenCV libraries to render a video. One of the main issues I get is that maven reports an error while trying to load a dependency, the native library it uses. All the solutions I checked here, on GitHub and everywhere else didn't bear fruit.

This is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>javaopencvbook</id>
      <url>https://raw.github.com/JavaOpenCVBook/code/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
    </repositories>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javaopencvbook</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencvjar</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javaopencvbook</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencvjar-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <classifier>natives-windows-x86_64</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>


  <build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            <mainClass>com.mycompany.mavenproject1.App</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>copy-dependencies</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.mavennatives</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-nativedependencies-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.7</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>unpacknatives</id>
          <phase>generate-resources</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>copy</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

This should create opencvjar-3.0.0.jar and opencvjar-runtime-3.0.0-natives-windows-x86_64.jar

The systems paths required for this should also be set. In %PATH% variable I have added the path to native .jar. In my case, project is located at

> D:\AleksandarRakic\Java Projects\mavenproject1

while the native library is at

> D:\AleksandarRakic\Java Projects\mavenproject1\target\natives

I am using **NetBeans 8.2**. When I Clean & Build the project it show the following error/warning:

```
The POM for org.javaopencvbook:opencvjar-runtime:jar:natives-windows-x86_64:3.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
```

The error above persists, no matter what version of OpenCV I use. I tried also putting 3.1.0 version but then it also says the core jar is missing.

I lost two days trying to crack this, any help is welcome.

Comment: do you have two projects ? one for library and another for project ? Could you please post full last lines for the error ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with maven and OpenCV version.

Maven would not load the natives .dll if I set the OpenCV version to 3.0.0 and wouldn't load that and core .jar if I put version 3.1.0

I did the obvious thing and made a blank project without maven, added the correct libraries and it ran just fine